# Snowflake Pipe creation with SNS topic fails with the following error : Invalid Parameter

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I am trying to create a snowflake pipe and it fails with the following error

```
090040 (XX000): Pipe Notifications bind failure "Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: Sns, Status Code: 400, Request ID: d7fbc360-1faf-5216-bfab-9f037f6ac63d): AwsErrorDetails(errorMessage=Invalid parameter: TopicArn, errorCode=InvalidParameter, serviceName=Sns)"
```

```
create pipe PROJECT.PUBLIC.mypipe
  auto_ingest=true
  aws_sns_topic='arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:4xxxxxxxx:SNSexample'
  as
    copy into PROJECT.PUBLIC.LOADING_STATION(INFO)
    from (select $1 from @REFERENCE_STATION)
```

Here is a documentation for reference https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#prerequisite-create-an-amazon-sns-topic-and-subscription

Can someone shed light on how to resolve this.

Here is the policy in SNS

```
>   "Version": "2008-10-17",   "Id": "__default_policy_ID",  
> "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Principal": {
>         "AWS": "*"
>       },
>       "Action": [
>         "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
>         "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
>         "SNS:AddPermission",
>         "SNS:RemovePermission",
>         "SNS:DeleteTopic",
>         "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
>         "SNS:Receive"
>       ],
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:accountid:SNSexample.fifo",
>       "Condition": {
>         "StringEquals": {
>           "AWS:SourceOwner": "snowflakeaccountid"
>         }
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       "Sid": "1",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Principal": {
>         "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::snowflakeaccountid:user/cie40000-s"
>       },
>       "Action": "sns:Subscribe",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:myaccountid:SNSexample.fifo"
>     },
>     {
>       "Sid": "s3-event-notifier",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Principal": {
>         "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
>       },
>       "Action": "SNS:Publish",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:myaccountid:SNSexample.fifo",
>       "Condition": {
>         "ArnLike": {
>           "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucketname"
>         }
>       }
>     }   ] }
```

Comment: Is your bucket name **SNSexample.fifo**? And what is **bucketname** in the policy?

Comment: Can you try the SNS with standard option and try?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution for this?